# How to extend or override default graphql query, mutation or schema

Tags: graphql

I want to include some changes in default graphql response but no idea how can I do that and what is the right way to do that as there is not documentation available there. Do I have to create always new graphql APIs(without referencing old one) in order or extend prev. one.

Please let me know if anyone has already done this.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Steps to extend the default mutation:

1. Create a schema.graphqls file in you Module->etc->schema.graphqls.
2. Copy the schema from the core module and paste it in your schema.graphql file.
3. Add parameters.
4. Change resolver class from your custom class e.g Module->Model->Resolver->Test.php.
5. Get the new parameters added to schema in resolver class using args.

Example:
I want to add an extar parameter to quote graphql mutation for **EstimateShippingCostsAddress**

Default schema and mutation:

```
type Query {
    getPaymentMethods(guestCartId: String): [PaymentMethod] @resolver(class: "\\ScandiPWA\\QuoteGraphQl\\Model\\Resolver\\GetPaymentMethods")
    getCartForCustomer(guestCartId: String): QuoteData @resolver(class: "\\ScandiPWA\\QuoteGraphQl\\Model\\Resolver\\GetCartForCustomer")
    getOrderList: OrderList @resolver(class: "\\ScandiPWA\\QuoteGraphQl\\Model\\Resolver\\OrderListResolver") @doc(description: "The Sales Order query returns information about a Sales order")
    getOrderById(id: Int!): Order @resolver(class: "\\ScandiPWA\\QuoteGraphQl\\Model\\Resolver\\ExpandedOrderResolver") @doc(description: "The Sales Order query returns information about a Sales order")
}

type Mutation {
    estimateShippingCosts(address: EstimateShippingCostsAddress!, guestCartId: String): [ShippingMethod] @resolver(class: "\\ScandiPWA\\QuoteGraphQl\\Model\\Resolver\\EstimateShippingCosts")
    saveAddressInformation(addressInformation: SaveAddressInformation!, guestCartId: String): PaymentDetails @resolver(class: "\\ScandiPWA\\QuoteGraphQl\\Model\\Resolver\\SaveAddressInformation")
    saveCartItem(cartItem: CartItemInput!, guestCartId: String): Query @resolver(class:"\\ScandiPWA\\QuoteGraphQl\\Model\\Resolver\\SaveCartItem")
    removeCartItem(guestCartId: String, item_id: Int!): Query @resolver(class:"\\ScandiPWA\\QuoteGraphQl\\Model\\Resolver\\RemoveCartItem")
    applyCoupon(guestCartId: String, coupon_code: String!): Query @resolver(class:"\\ScandiPWA\\QuoteGraphQl\\Model\\Resolver\\ApplyCoupon")
    removeCoupon(guestCartId: String): Query @resolver(class:"\\ScandiPWA\\QuoteGraphQl\\Model\\Resolver\\RemoveCoupon")

    # Magento 2 overrides to stop sending logged in user cart IDs
    s_setPaymentMethodOnCart(input: S_SetPaymentMethodOnCartInput!): SetPaymentMethodOnCartOutput @resolver(class: "\\ScandiPWA\\QuoteGraphQl\\Model\\Resolver\\SetPaymentMethodOnCart")
    s_placeOrder(guestCartId: String): PlaceOrderOutput @resolver(class: "\\ScandiPWA\\QuoteGraphQl\\Model\\Resolver\\PlaceOrder")
    s_setBillingAddressOnCart(input: S_SetBillingAddressOnCartInput): SetBillingAddressOnCartOutput @resolver(class: "\\ScandiPWA\\QuoteGraphQl\\Model\\Resolver\\SetBillingAddressOnCart")
}

input S_SetBillingAddressOnCartInput {
    guest_cart_id: String
    billing_address: BillingAddressInput!
}

input S_SetPaymentMethodOnCartInput {
    guest_cart_id: String
    payment_method: PaymentMethodInput!
}

input CartItemInput {
    id: CartItemId
    sku: String
    quantity: Float!
    quote_id: String
    item_id: Int
    product_type: String
    product_option: ProductOptionInput
}

input CartItemId {
    sku: String,
    item_id: Int
}

input ProductOptionInput {
    extension_attributes: ExtensionsAttributeInput
}

input ExtensionsAttributeInput {
    configurable_item_options: [ConfigurableItemOptionsInput]
    customizable_options: [CustomizableOptionsInput]
    customizable_options_multi: [CustomizableOptionsInput]
    bundle_options: [BundleOptionInput!]
}

input ConfigurableItemOptionsInput {
    option_id: String
    option_value: Int
}

input CustomizableOptionsInput {
    option_id: String!
    option_value: String
}

input PaymentInformation {
    billing_address: AddressInput!
    paymentMethod: PaymentMethodInput!
}

input PaymentMethodInput {
    method: String
    additional_data: PaymentMethodAdditionalData
}

input PaymentMethodAdditionalData {
    payment_method_nonce: String
    cc_stripejs_token: String
    cc_save: Boolean
}

input AddressInput {
    method: String
    region: String
    region_id: Int
    region_code: String
    country_id: String
    postcode: String
    city: String
    firstname: String
    lastname: String
    email: String
    telephone: String
    company: String
    street: [String]
}





input EstimateShippingCostsAddress {
    region: String
    region_id: Int
    region_code: String
    country_id: String
    postcode: String
    city: String
    firstname: String
    lastname: String
    email: String
    telephone: String
    street: [String]
    customer_id: Int
    same_as_billing: Int
}

input SaveAddressInformation {
    shipping_address: AddressInput!
    billing_address: AddressInput!
    shipping_carrier_code: String
    shipping_method_code: String
}

type QuoteData implements TotalsObject  {
    is_virtual: Boolean
}

type PaymentTotals implements TotalsObject {
}

type PaymentDetails {
    payment_methods: [PaymentMethod]
    totals: PaymentTotals
}

type PaymentMethod {
    code: String
    title: String
}

interface TotalsObject @typeResolver(class: "\\ScandiPWA\\QuoteGraphQl\\Model\\Resolver\\TotalsObject") {
    items_count: Int
    customer_is_guest: Boolean
    store_id: Int
    customer_tax_class_id: Int
    items_qty: Float
    coupon_code: String
    grand_total: Float
    base_grand_total: Float
    subtotal: Float
    base_subtotal: Float
    discount_amount: Float
    base_discount_amount: Float
    subtotal_with_discount: Float
    base_subtotal_with_discount: Float
    shipping_amount: Float
    base_shipping_amount: Float
    shipping_discount_amount: Float
    base_shipping_discount_amount: Float
    tax_amount: Float
    base_tax_amount: Float
    weee_tax_applied_amount: Float
    shipping_tax_amount: Float
    base_shipping_tax_amount: Float
    subtotal_incl_tax: Float
    shipping_incl_tax: Float
    base_shipping_incl_tax: Float
    base_currency_code: String
    quote_currency_code: String
    items: [TotalsItem]
}

type TotalsItem {
    item_id: Int
    qty: Float
    price: Float
    base_price: Float
    row_total: Float
    base_row_total: Float
    row_total_with_discount: Float
    tax_amount: Float
    base_tax_amount: Float
    tax_percent: Float
    discount_amount: Float
    base_discount_amount: Float
    discount_percent: Float
    price_incl_tax: Float
    base_price_incl_tax: Float
    row_total_incl_tax: Float
    base_row_total_incl_tax: Float
    weee_tax_applied_amount: Float
    weee_tax_applied: Float
    options: String
    name: String
    sku: String
    customizable_options: [SelectedCustomizableOption]
    bundle_options: [SelectedBundleOption]
    product: ProductInterface
}

type TotalsSegment {
    code: String
    title: String
    value: Float
    extension_attributes: ExtensionAttributes
}

type ExtensionAttributes {
    tax_grandtotal_details: [TaxGrandTotalDetails]
}

type TaxGrandTotalDetails {
    # rates:
    amount: Float
    group_id: Int
}

type ShippingMethod {
    carrier_code: String
    method_code: String
    carrier_title: String
    method_title: String
    error_message: String
    amount: Float
    base_amount: Float
    price_excl_tax: Float
    price_incl_tax: Float
    available: Boolean
}

type OrderList {
    items: [Order]
}

type BaseOrderInfo {
    id: Int
    total_qty_ordered: Int
    increment_id: String
    created_at: String
    status: String
    status_label: String
    grand_total: Float
    sub_total: Float
}

type Order {
    base_order_info: BaseOrderInfo
    payment_info: PaymentInfo
    shipping_info: ShippingInfo
    order_products: [ProductInterface] @resolver(class: "\\ScandiPWA\\QuoteGraphQl\\Model\\Resolver\\ProductResolver")
}

type PaymentInfo {
    method: String
    cc_owner: String
    cc_last_4: String
    cc_type: String
    additional_information: AdditionalCustomerInfo
}

type AdditionalCustomerInfo {
    bank: String
    method_title: String
    credit_type: String
    month: Int
    customer_info: CreditCustomerInfo
}

type CreditCustomerInfo {
    first_name: String
    last_name: String
    iin_number: String
    middle_name: String
    phone: String
}

type ShippingInfo {
    shipping_method: String
    shipping_address: OrderCustomerAddress
    shipping_description: String
    shipping_amount: Float
    tracking_numbers: [String]
}

type OrderCustomerAddress {
    city: String
    company: String
    country_id: String
    customer_id: Int
    firstname: String
    id: Int
    lastname: String
    middlename: String
    prefix: String
    region: String
    street: String
    telephone: String
    district: String
    house_number: String
    apartment_number: String
    postomat_code: String
    store_pickup_code: String
    post_office_code: String
    is_b2b: String
    postcode: String
    organizationname: String
    organizationbin: String
    organizationaddress: String
    organizationiic: String
    organizationbik: String
}

interface ProductInterface {
    quantity: Float
    row_total: Float
    original_price: Float
    license_key: String
}
```

Extended schema:

```
type Mutation {
    estimateShippingCosts(address: EstimateShippingCostsAddress!, guestCartId: String, CustomData: EstimateData): [ShippingMethod] @resolver(class: "\\NameSpace\\Module\\Model\\Resolver\\EstimateShippingCosts")
}

input EstimateData {
    data: String
}
```

you can see that i have changed the mutation of **EstimateShippingCosts** by adding a new parameter **CustomData** ans changed the resolver class.

now in resolver class you can get the **CustomData** in args.

**EstimateShippingCosts.php**

```
    <?php
    
    
    declare(strict_types=1);
    
    namespace NameSpace\Module\Model\Resolver;
    
    use Magento\Customer\Api\Data\AddressInterfaceFactory;
    use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Config\Element\Field;
    use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Query\Resolver\ContextInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Query\Resolver\Value;
    use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Query\ResolverInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Schema\Type\ResolveInfo;
    use Magento\Quote\Api\Data\EstimateAddressInterface;
    use Magento\Quote\Api\Data\EstimateAddressInterfaceFactory;
    use Magento\Quote\Api\Data\ShippingMethodInterface;
    use Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteIdMaskFactory;
    use Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteIdMask;
    use Magento\Quote\Model\ShippingMethodManagement;
    use Magento\Quote\Model\Webapi\ParamOverriderCartId;
    
  
    class EstimateShippingCosts implements ResolverInterface {
        /**
         * @var QuoteIdMaskFactory
         */
        protected $quoteIdMaskFactory;
    
        /**
         * @var ShippingMethodManagement
         */
        protected $shippingMethodManagement;
    
        /**
         * @var ParamOverriderCartId
         */
        protected $overriderCartId;
    
        /**
         * @var AddressInterfaceFactory
         */
        protected $addressInterfaceFactory;
    
        /**
         * EstimateShippingCosts constructor.
         * @param QuoteIdMaskFactory $quoteIdMaskFactory
         * @param ShippingMethodManagement $shippingMethodManagement
         * @param ParamOverriderCartId $overriderCartId
         * @param EstimateAddressInterfaceFactory $addressInterfaceFactory
         */
        public function __construct(
            QuoteIdMaskFactory $quoteIdMaskFactory,
            ShippingMethodManagement $shippingMethodManagement,
            ParamOverriderCartId $overriderCartId,
            EstimateAddressInterfaceFactory $addressInterfaceFactory
        ) {
            $this->addressInterfaceFactory = $addressInterfaceFactory;
            $this->quoteIdMaskFactory = $quoteIdMaskFactory;
            $this->shippingMethodManagement = $shippingMethodManagement;
            $this->overriderCartId = $overriderCartId;
        }
    
        /**
         * Fetches the data from persistence models and format it according to the GraphQL schema.
         *
         * @param \Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Config\Element\Field $field
         * @param ContextInterface $context
         * @param ResolveInfo $info
         * @param array|null $value
         * @param array|null $args
         * @throws \Exception
         * @return mixed|Value
         */
        public function resolve(
            Field $field,
            $context,
            ResolveInfo $info,
            array $value = null,
            array $args = null
        ) {

**$CustomData= $args['CustomData']['data'];**

            /** @var EstimateAddressInterface $address */
            $shippingAddressObject = $this->addressInterfaceFactory->create([ 'data' => $args['address'] ]);
    
            $cartId = isset($args['guestCartId'])
                ? $this->quoteIdMaskFactory->create()->load($args['guestCartId'], 'masked_id')->getQuoteId()
                : $this->overriderCartId->getOverriddenValue();
    
            $shippingMethods = $this->shippingMethodManagement->estimateByAddress($cartId, $shippingAddressObject);
    
            return array_map(function($shippingMethod) {
                /** @var ShippingMethodInterface $shippingMethod */
                return [
                    'carrier_code' => $shippingMethod->getCarrierCode(),
                    'method_code' => $shippingMethod->getMethodCode(),
                    'carrier_title' => $shippingMethod->getCarrierTitle(),
                    'method_title' => $shippingMethod->getMethodTitle(),
                    'error_message' => $shippingMethod->getErrorMessage(),
                    'amount' => $shippingMethod->getAmount(),
                    'base_amount' => $shippingMethod->getBaseAmount(),
                    'price_excl_tax' => $shippingMethod->getPriceExclTax(),
                    'price_incl_tax' => $shippingMethod->getPriceInclTax(),
                    'available' => $shippingMethod->getAvailable()
                ];
            }, $shippingMethods);
        }
    }
```

query will be same for this just add a new parameter that you have added into it.

Answer (score 3):

If I am not wrong you meant to ask  What if we’re adding a custom attribute, e.g., an attribute we’ve added to the database? And how we gonna deal with making that attribute available to *GraphQL*. So let's proceed with an example:

Let’s assume you want to add the **parent_item_id** as an attribute available through the GraphQL Quote Endpoint.Now, you may already be aware, **parent_item_id** is an existing field (it’s not a new database attribute). But currently, it’s not supported through the native GraphQL Quote Endpoint – so it’s not accessible via GraphQL responses. We’ll walk through a simple example to add it:

First, We’ll create a module:

```
// File: app/code/GraphQlHandson/Example/registration.php
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'GraphQlHandson_Example',
    __DIR__
);
```

Next, We’ll add our etc/schema.graphqls file:

```
// File: app/code/GraphQlHandson/Example/etc/schema.graphqls
interface CartItemInterface @typeResolver(class: "Magento\\QuoteGraphQl\\Model\\Resolver\\CartItemTypeResolver") {
    parent_item_id: Int
}
```

Now, refresh your database / cache:

`php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

…That’s it! On the client side, We can send a GraphQL query that looks like this:

`query {
    cart {
        items {
            parent_item_id
        }
    }
}`

*(Obviously in a real-world scenario, you would request additional information).*

Now, the only point that confusing at first glance is the interface definition in the **schema.graphqls** file. …Where did we get that? Well, if you look in the native Quote graphql module:

```
// File>: vendor/magento/module-quote-graph-ql/etc/schema.graphqls
...
type SimpleCartItem implements CartItemInterface @doc(description: "Simple Cart Item") {
    customizable_options: [SelectedCustomizableOption] @resolver(class: "Magento\\QuoteGraphQl\\Model\\Resolver\\CustomizableOptions")
}

type VirtualCartItem implements CartItemInterface @doc(description: "Virtual Cart Item") {
    customizable_options: [SelectedCustomizableOption] @resolver(class: "Magento\\QuoteGraphQl\\Model\\Resolver\\CustomizableOptions")
}

interface CartItemInterface @typeResolver(class: "Magento\\QuoteGraphQl\\Model\\Resolver\\CartItemTypeResolver") {
    id: String!
    quantity: Float!
    product: ProductInterface!
}
...
```

You can see above, that by default Magento 2 does several things:

- Defines an interface **CartItemInterface** which is used to represent
  cart items.
- Defines concrete implementations of that interface for
  different product types.
- Defines the fields available through GraphQL
  for each of them.

  So, by default, the only available fields for an
  item are id, quantity, product — the last of which is a complex
  ProductInterface type

In our custom module, all we did was copy the interface definition and start adding new properties to it.

> That’s an important point to remember – the GraphQL definitions
>   function more like layout xml in Magento 2, and less like typical
>   extension_attributes. The beauty of this is that we can freely add new
>   types, modify queries, etc.
>
> Hope this provide a clear glimpse on how you can modify the GraphQL queries by adding custom or new attributes. If yes, then kindly upvote it and mark it as an answer. Thanks!

Comment: Please always provide credits to the original post, in this case: https://www.cadence-labs.com/2019/09/extending-graphql-endpoints-in-magento-2/

Comment: The easy way to extend the interface schema. But with my question, I want to extend of Query type so how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

new attribute "addtocarttype

```
 type Mutation {
    addProductsToCart(cartId: String!, cartItems: [CartItemInput!]!): AddProductsToCartOutput @doc(description:"Add any type of product to the cart") @resolver(class: "vendor\\module\\Model\\Resolver\\AddProductsToCart")
}

input CartItemInput {
    sku: String
    quantity: Float!
    quote_id: String
    item_id: Int
    product_type: String
    addtocarttype: Int
}
```

$addProductsToCartOutput->getCart() this returns quote so use like

```
$quote = $addProductsToCartOutput->getCart();
    $items = $quote->getAllItems();
    $max = 0;
    $lastItem = null;
      foreach ($items as $item){
        if ($item->getId() > $max) {
            if($item->getSku() == $sku){
                $lastItem = $item;
                break;
            }
            $max = $item->getId();
            $lastItem = $item;

        }
    }
    if ($lastItem){
        $lastItem->setData('addtocarttype',$addtocarttype);
    }
      $quote->save();
```

now return

```
return [
        'cart' => [
            'model' => $quote,
        ],
        'user_errors' => array_map(
            function (Error $error) {
                return [
                    'code' => $error->getCode(),
                    'message' => $error->getMessage(),
                    'path' => [$error->getCartItemPosition()]
                ];
            },
            $addProductsToCartOutput->getErrors()
        )
    ];
```